# GetTokenInformation returns ERROR_NOACCESS

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to get the SID associated with a process I am able to get a Handle on since I will be running this program as a non-admin. I am able to get a handle via OpenProcess, and OpenProcessToken(which passes), but when I try to call GetTokenInformation for a second time it fails and returns an error code 998. When I look at the MSDN docs it shows that it is an ERROR_NOACCESS. The only thing I could think of is the permission of the handle, but I believe TOKEN_QUERY should be good enough. Below is the code I have so far:

```
HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
if (hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    printf("Could not open handle via CreateToolhelp32 Snapshot() \n ");
    system("exit");
}

PROCESSENTRY32 pe = { sizeof(pe) };
if (!Process32First(hSnapshot, &pe)) {
    printf("Process32First failed :( \n");
}

while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &pe)) {
       
    HANDLE OGHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pe.th32ProcessID);
    HANDLE tokenHandle = NULL;
    DWORD returnLength = 0;
    PTOKEN_USER user = NULL;
   
    if (OGHandle != NULL || OGHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        if (OpenProcessToken(OGHandle, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE, &tokenHandle)) {
            if (!GetTokenInformation(tokenHandle, TokenUser,(LPVOID )user, 0, &returnLength)) { //This should fail since I don't know the buffer length
              
                if (!GetTokenInformation(tokenHandle, TokenUser, (LPVOID)user, returnLength, &returnLength)) { //This should pass since I know buffer length
                    printf("GetTokenInfo() failed with a %d error code\n", GetLastError());
                }
                
            }
        }

    }
   
    printf("Process ID: %d  , PPID: %d  , Path: %ws \n", pe.th32ProcessID, pe.th32ParentProcessID, pe.szExeFile );
    CloseHandle(OGHandle);
    CloseHandle(tokenHandle);
}


CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
```

Comment: See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-gettokeninformation) for `TokenInformationLength`: *"Specifies the size, in bytes, of the buffer pointed to by the `TokenInformation` parameter. **If `TokenInformation` is `NULL`, this parameter must be zero.**"*

Comment: Alright, I modified by first call to GetTokenInformation to : ```GetTokenInformation(tokenHandle, TokenUser,NULL, 0, &returnLength)``` , however I still get the same error code. After the first call of the function it will error out and return the size in bytes for the TokenInformationLength correct? If that is the case I don't get why the second call to the function returns an error.

Comment: The issue isn't the first call. It's the second call that would either need to pass 0 as the `TokenInformationLength` parameter, or a valid pointer to a buffer of at least `TokenInformationLength` bytes as the `TokenInformation` parameter. As written, the code passes a `NULL` pointer, but a non-null length parameter. That's not a meaningful combination.

Comment: Besides, the expectation that the call would produce a valid result through `ReturnLength` only when it fails is unfounded. If it fails then all `[out]` parameters have indeterminate values. In case you haven't noticed, you're skipping over the first process in the process snapshot (the one returned from `Process32First`).

Comment: This code inevitably is going to encounter a system process or process running with a different account that provides *no access* to this info.  Be selective, calling OpenProcess() only the process you want to peek at.

Comment: Honestly, I give up. I found someone who did something similar to what I was trying to do. I think using WTSEnumerateProcesses and getting the PSID from that will do the trick. My end goal was to enumerate the username from SID from each process I could get a valid handle to as a non-admin

Comment: Process ID's are meaningless in isolation. You will need to hold a handle to the process (directly, or indirectly) to know whether the ID still refers to the same thing. As for the specific API: It follows a common pattern that's frequently used when a system service returns data of arbitrary size into a caller-provided buffer. You first call it with `NULL`/`0` as the pointer/size pair to query the required size. On success, you allocate a buffer of appropriate size, and call the API again with `buf_ptr`/`buf_size`.